# How to change or add a route to handle my URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

How to change or add a route to handle this URL?

http://localhost:80/Advers/View/blablabla/500

"blablabla" will change on any url

"500" is an Id that i need it.

my action is (i want to pass 500 to this action):

```
public ActionResult View(string id)
    { 
       return view();
    }
```

my default rout is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Default",
             url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Advers", action = "View", 
              id = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a custom route (do this before your default route is registered):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CustomRoute",
    url: "Advers/View/{someparameter}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Advers", action = "View", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And your controller method should look like this:

```
public ActionResult View(string someparameter, string id)
{ 
   return view();
}
```